# Correct JAX-RS media type matching for JSON provider

Tags: json, jax-rs, resteasy, jackson2

The official JSON media type is `application/json`. The RESTEasy provider for Jackson, `ResteasyJackson2Provider`, specifies the media types like this:

```
@Provider
@Consumes({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
@Produces({"application/*+json", "text/json"})
public class ResteasyJackson2Provider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
…
```

I don't get it. I understand that `"application/*+json"` would match e.g. `application/foo+json`. But would it match `application/json` without the plus `+` sign? Is that in the JAX-RS specification? It doesn't coincide with how I expect a wildcard to work, unless JAX-RS media type pattern matching has some understanding of media type sub-component semantics.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in [JAX-RS spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html)  (sub types are concret or wildcard, no combination) and [`MediaType#isCompatible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#isCompatible-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-) can't handle it. `application/*+json`seems to be wrong or a vendor feature of RestEasy.

Comment: Yes this specific of resteasy. And "application/json" match "application/*+json". See [MediaTypeMap.SubTypeMap.getPossible](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/c68a7a679e0bc872e48da75eb357f6246df10ec7/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/core/MediaTypeMap.java#L227)

Comment: But is it a standard part of JAX-RS? Would I expect this to work with other JAX-RS implementations? Please provide a separate answer so that I can mark it as correct if you give a reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about media type suffix in JAX-RS spec. Each provider processing suffix as it like.

I testes my custom provider (produces `application/*+json` media type) with 3 JAX-RS implementations:

- Jersey (with Jettison JSON provider) - don't process service produces `application/json` media type
- RESTeasy (internal JSON provider) - process service produces
  `application/json` media type
- Apache CFX (internal JSON provider) - process service produces
  `application/json` media type (if
  `PARTIAL_HIERARCHICAL_MEDIA_SUBTYPE_CHECK` property is `true`)

My recommdenation - don't trust `*+json` media type if you want use different JAX-RS implementations. Add explicit `application/json`.